# Sonata Admin conflict between 'template' and 'editable'

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am currently working on a small personal project to learn how to manipulate Symfony and Sonata, and I find myself confronted with a small problem. I have constrained one of my variables to a "template" in "configureListFields" but I can not submit it to "editable". I can do the one without the other but not both at the same time if not the "editable" bug as I show you a bit further down.

List :

```
            $listMapper->add('status', 'string', array(
            'template' => 'WebBundle:Default:list_client.html.twig',
            'label'=> 'Status'))
```

Form :

```
            $formMapper->add('Status', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Client' => 'Client',
                'Ex-Client' => 'Ex-Client',
                'Prospect' => 'Prospect')))
```

Template :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
<div>
    <p class="ClientStatus {% if object.Status == 'Ex-Client' %}
        label label-danger
       {% elseif object.Status == 'Client'   %}
       label label-success
       {%  else %}
       label label-info

    {%  endif %}" >
        {{ object.Status }}
    </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

View with that config :

[image: view]

### Second config :

```
            $listMapper->add('status', 'choice', array(
            'choices'=>array(
                "Client"=>"Client",
                "New Client"=>"New Client",
                "Ex-Client"=>"Ex Client"
            ),
            'label'=> 'Status',
            'editable'=>true))
```

View :

[image: view]

### Third Config :

```
            ->add('status', 'choice', array(
            'choices'=>array(
                "Client"=>"Client",
                "New Client"=>"New Client",
                "Ex-Client"=>"Ex Client"
            ),
            'template' => 'WebBundle:Default:list_client.html.twig',
            'label'=> 'Status',
            'editable'=>true))
```

view :

[image: view]

So there seems to be a conflict between "template" and "editable" opinions on how to handle this problem ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [list_choice](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/152beeaed06683ef1bfe5b2dcbc1a3cd9547fe89/Resources/views/CRUD/list_choice.html.twig) template that is provided with the Sonata sources.

```
# SonataAdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list_choice.html.twig
{% set is_editable =
    field_description.options.editable is defined and
    field_description.options.editable and
    admin.hasAccess('edit', object)
%}

{% set x_editable_type = field_description.type|sonata_xeditable_type %}

{% if is_editable and x_editable_type %}
    {% block field_span_attributes %}
        {% spaceless %}
            {{ parent() }}
            data-source="{{ field_description|sonata_xeditable_choices|json_encode }}"
        {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

They check if the field is editable and add `data-source` attribute to the `field_span_attributes` block of the parent [base_list_field](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/205554e8e115d8c09f3a075bebed4ceccaab3b2d/Resources/views/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig#L59) template part:

```
<span {% block field_span_attributes %}class="x-editable"
    data-type="{{ xEditableType }}"
    data-value="{{ data_value }}"
    data-title="{{ field_description.label|trans({}, field_description.translationDomain) }}"
    data-pk="{{ admin.id(object) }}"
    data-url="{{ url }}" {% endblock %}>
    {{ block('field') }}
</span>
```

So try adding the data-source in your custom template as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't understand what do you mean by " try adding the data-source in your custom templates as well". Cause i'm suppose too extend base_list_field but i can't extend twice. Can i call 2 template ? And if i try to just add     {% set data-value = ["Client", "Ex-client","Prospect"] %}      it won't work

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me:

If you check the HTML code, on your element choice, of your site you can detect if any tag is missing, for example the code below is the code that generate the page without the 'template' option configured:

```html
    <span class="x-editable label-info editable editable-click editable-open" data-type="select" 
data-value="Rechazado" 
data-title="Estado" 
data-pk="4" 
data-url="/eventos/web/app_dev.php/admin/core/set-object-field-value?context=list&amp;field=estado&amp;objectId=4&amp;code=admin.evento" 
data-source="[{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Aprobado&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Pendiente&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Pendiente&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Rechazado&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Rechazado&quot;}]" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover786605">
</span>
```

And now check the code generated when the 'template' option is on set

```html
<span class="x-editable label label-danger editable editable-click" 
data-type="select" 
data-value="Rechazado" 
data-title="Estado" 
data-pk="4" 
data-url="/eventos/web/app_dev.php/admin/core/set-object-field-value?context=list&amp;field=estado&amp;objectId=4&amp;code=admin.evento">
</span>
```

The data-source field is missing and that is the reason why its crash.

The solution is simple (isn't the best but it is something) on your template add the data-source with the data of your choice.